# Contact picker with search function

Tags: android, contacts, picker

This question[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774446/contact-picker-in-a-dialog) describes a way how to show list of phone numbers and select one of them if my app needs a phone number. But image if I have a huge contact list, it is not enough to just show list but possibility for filtering (by contact's name) is also needed. Is there a standard way to show phones list with picking possibility and with filtering possibility? (I wouldn't like to invent my own)

Is there a solution for the problem for sdk 2.0 and lower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ContactsContract.Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) and then the Flag [CONTENT_FILTER_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_FILTER_URI).

Comment: I guess this will not work for Android 1.5. Is there a good approach for 1.5?

Comment: no this is only 2.0 and above. you didn't mentioned that you need it for 1.5 and above. sorry.

Comment: This article (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) contains some details including how to support old and new api.

Comment: @Roflcoptr I'm lost here, since CONTENT_FILTER_URI is an Uri, how is it possible to use it like a flag (int)?